# React JS - How this data is set in the setState after promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setUser);
    return () => {
      console.log("CleanUp Code");
    };
  }, []);
```

How the set State is automatiocally set with this method   .then(setUser); --> **How the state is set with this method any explanation**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then` is designed so that you pass a function into it. When the promise resolves, your function will be called and will be passed in the value that the promise resolved to.

So for example, you can create a brand new function, such as `(res) => res.json()`, and pass that function in to be called when the promise resolves. Or you can pass in a function which already exists, such as `setUser`. And again, that function will be called when the promise resolves. Calling `setUser` sets the state.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
      .then((res) => setUser(res.data))
      .catch(err=>res.json(message: err.message));
    return () => {
      console.log("CleanUp Code");
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Please include an explanation with your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
const [user, setUser] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((res) => setUser(res.data))
  .then(setUser);
return () => {
  console.log("CleanUp Code");
};}, [])
```